# Is it possible to access features of newer SDKs with an old SDK?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm still on an older Xcode version and my macOS SDK is still 10.13. Now I'd like to access the constant `NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua` that is not available before 10.14. Unfortunately, its value is not numeric but it is defined as an extern `NSAppearanceName`, i.e.

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSAppearanceName const NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_14);
```

Obviously, the linker is unable to resolve this reference because it doesn't exist in the 10.13 SDK.

Still, I'm wondering if there is a way to manually import this 10.14 constant into my program so that I can use it even though I'm still on the 10.13 SDK. Is that possible somehow?